# A couple of typo mistakes

Tags: i18n

Sorry if this is not the right place for this signalization:

I found a mistake on civicrm_state_province table regarding Potugal and Coimbra state/province, typed as "Colmbra".
The other group of typo mistake id that of all Poland state/provionce, typed in lower case.
Best regards,
Pino Vasarelli
pino@vasarelli.it

Answer (score 1):

Pino, thanks for reporting this I have submitted a PR to fix above typo

For [Potugal and Coimbra state/province](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17106)

For [Poland state/provionce, typed in lower case](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17107)

Would you mind doing some test or adding some thoughts on appropriate PR to speedup the merge process?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting. For Poland, are you in Poland? It seems strange they would *all* be wrong so it might be correct that they are lower case - see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_Poland#Voivodeships. Or maybe the wikipedia article is a different context. I don't know.

Usually the best place to report this is at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues